# Public gpg key disappears after I import my new private key, why is it doing this?

Tags: linux, encryption

I have tried to import my public key in the command line, but at first it worked then after importing the private key it disappeared when viewing it in the seahorse application.

[Image showing what I did in the terminal with the gpg command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OArl.jpg)

Comment: I've did some research and it apparently is a bug.

Comment: Could you please add a link where you found that it is a bug. I never experienced such behavior so it really interesting to know this

Comment: I don't think it is relatable to my problem but it does seem like it is a bug. https://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/gpg-cannot-import-public-key